# Offline map using mapsforge in android

Tags: android, dictionary, offline-caching

How can i implement offline map in android. I tried it with mapsforge library.
It does not provides binary map file for Wisconsin state. So How can create my own map binary file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need two things:

1. a program that allows you to use the mapsforge library. Concerning this, you can stick with the program called AdvancedMapViewer which comes as an example with the library.
2. a mapfile. Bascially you have to create your own mapfile from OpenStreetMap data. This is done with a plugin for Osmosis. This plugin is described here:

https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md

In short it works like this:

- Install Osmosis (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)
- Install the plugin (https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md)
- Download the data (e.g. from geofabrik.de: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/wisconsin-latest.osm.pbf)
- run the osmosis task, thus run this on a shell (with osmosis in your PATH):

  `osmosis --read-pbf wisconsin-latest.osm.pbf --mapfile-writer file=wisconsin.map`

then put the created file wisconsin.map on your device and load it from AdvancedMapViewer.

Comment: Could you please add information **where** to put the file on the device? I suppose there is a default location where mapsforge tries to find the files.

Comment: just put it at the route of the sdcard and it will find it.

Comment: What if I want to include the map into an android app package?

Comment: Then you will have to include it as an asset and copy it to local storage before using it.